# dplyr: how to (concisely) use a mutate conditional on different cases?

Tags: r, dplyr

Consider the following example

```
data <- data_frame(name = c('A','B','C','C',NA,'D'))

> data
# A tibble: 6 × 1
   name
  <chr>
1     A
2     B
3     C
4     C
5  <NA>
6     D
```

Here, I know that the variable `name` actually maps to `'A' -> 'one'` and `'B' -> 'two'`. I would simply like to create a variable that gets the mapping value. Of course, in my original dataset I have many more cases to map.

Something that **does not** work is the following.

```
data <- data %>%
  mutate(mapping = ifelse(name == 'A', 'one', name),
         mapping = ifelse(name == 'B', 'two', name))
> data
# A tibble: 6 × 2
   name mapping
  <chr>   <chr>
1     A       A
2     B     two
3     C       C
4     C       C
5  <NA>    <NA>
6     D       D
```

What is wrong here? What is the most efficient way to do so in `dplyr`?

Many thanks!

Comment: I think the ifelse expressions should be ifelse(name == 'A', 'one', name). At the moment ifelse is looking for a variable named mapping in your data frame and it doesn't exist yet.

Comment: thanks but that still does not work properly

Comment: You could nest the ifelse statements if you're going to have to hard code all of the mapping values. i.e. `ifelse(name == 'A', 'one', ifelse(name == 'B', 'two', .... ))

Comment: A potentially more efficient approach would be to match the mapping values. For example: `vec <- c(A = "one", B = "two"); mutate(data, mapping = vec[match(name, names(vec))])`

Comment: thanks but I want to avoid nested ifelse at all costs. horrible syntax super error prone....

Comment: How is it failing? Do the A cases not resolve correctly? You may be redefining the variable mapping in your second call. Try nesting the ifelse statements?

Comment: Agreed - perhaps @docendodiscimus's approach is a better option

Comment: @GabrielFGeislerMesevage the error is kind of puzzling to me as well. I thought I could re-use variable defined in the same `mutate` step

Comment: @Noobie, you can do that (and as you see it does work). But the point is that `ifelse` returns a whole new vector each time and hence replaces all values from the first iteration. To avoid that, you'd need `mutate(data, mapping = ifelse(name == 'A', 'one', name), mapping = ifelse(name == 'B', 'two', mapping))` if you want to keep using ifelse

Comment: @docendodiscimus thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to avoid nested `ifelse` , you should simply create a mapping data frame and inner join with it .

```
mapping_df <- data.frame(name = c('A', 'B', 'C' . . . . 'Z'), mapping = c(1:26))

left_join(data, mapping_df, by = "name")
```

Comment: very smart. its unfortunate there is no out-of-the-box `dplyr` solution for that but this might actually be even better

Answer (score 2):

```
data %>% mutate(mapping = recode(name, A="one", B="two"))
```

Recode may be handy when there aren't too many replacements.

Answer (score 1):

For two values you could try something like:

```
data <- data %>%
    mutate(mapping = ifelse(name == 'A', 'one',
    ifelse(name == 'B', 'two', 'other')))
```

However you would be better off creating a separate data frame that contained the map and then using dplyr::left_join() to add it to your main df.